# What session are better to use?

Tags: 8, sessions

i already tried the private tempstorage class on local it is working. but when i put it on cloud it was not working anymore.

```
use Drupal\user\PrivateTempStoreFactory;

$session = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('my_modules');
$session_id = $session->set('session_id');
$session_uname = $session->set('session_username');

$session_id = $session->get('session_id');
$session_uname = $session->get('session_username');
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use sessions. This is how to access sessions inside classes:

```
class MymoduleSessionCounter {
  function increment(Request $request) {
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $value = $session->get('mymodule_count', 0);
    $session->set('mymodule_count', $value + 1);

    return $value;
  }
}
```

Change note: https://www.drupal.org/node/2380327

If you have procedural code in hooks, you can still use the D7 way and store the data in `$_SESSION[]` or get the session with:

```
$session = \Drupal::request()->getSession()
```